# Property 'app' does not exist on type 'cy & EventEmitter'

Tags: cypress

Source code from [Cypress on Rails](https://www.google.com/search?q=cypress+on+rails&oq=cypress+on+rails&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i22i30l3j69i60l3.2263j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

```
// spec/cypress/support/on-rails.ts

Cypress.Commands.add('app', function (name, command_options) {
  return cy
    .appCommands({ name: name, options: command_options })
    .then((body) => {
      return body[0];
    });
});
```

`spec/cypress/tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "module": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "types": ["cypress"],
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "include": ["**/*.ts"]
}
```

Results in

```
 Property 'app' does not exist on type 'cy & EventEmitter'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather old, but I recently ran across this issue.

The documents show a way to deal with Commands.
Here is a link to their document: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/typescript-support#Adding-child-or-dual-commands

cypress/support/index.ts

```
// load type definitions that come with Cypress module
/// <reference types="cypress" />

declare global {
  namespace Cypress {
    interface Chainable {
      /**
       * Custom command to type a few random words into input elements
       * @param count=3
       * @example cy.get('input').typeRandomWords()
       */
      typeRandomWords(
        count?: number,
        options?: Partial<TypeOptions>
      ): Chainable<Element>
    }
  }
}
```

cypress/support/index.ts

```
Cypress.Commands.add('typeRandomWords', { prevSubject: 'element' }, (
  subject /* :JQuery<HTMLElement> */,
  count = 3,
  options?
) => {
  return cy.wrap(subject).type(generateRandomWords(count), options)
})
```